# Inserting contents of a file with special characters using sed

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I want to replace a marker (REPLACETHIS) in file1.txt with the entire contents of file2.txt, which will include newlines and special characters.

An example of file2.txt's contents would be

```
<Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 1.2.3.4
        Allow from 5.6.7.8
</Location>
```

My general code, minus handling of special characters, would look something like this:

```
value=$(</home/name/scripts/file2.txt)
sed -i -e "s|REPLACETHIS|$value|" /home/name/scripts/file1.txt
```

What's the best way to go about handling this?

Comment: Do you have to use sed for this?

Comment: Is `REPLACETHIS` alone on its line, or can it be surrounded by other text (`beforehand-REPLACETHIS-afterwards`) on the same line of input?  From the sample content, it looks like you'd not be inserting in the middle of a line, which is a whole heap easier (`sed` can handle it, as shown by [randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161642/15168)).  If you are inserting in the middle of the line, I'd switch tools to Perl.

Comment: BTW, your use of `sed -i` here is compatible with GNU `sed`, but **not** with BSD `sed` -- on MacOS, for example, this will try to use `-e` as an extension to place on backup files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sed`, the best option for inserting text from file would be to use the [`r file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Read-text-from-a-file) command:

```
sed -i -e '/REPLACETHIS/{r /path/to/file2.txt' -e ';d;}' file1.txt
```

or, in the expanded form:

```
sed -i '/REPLACETHIS/ {
    r /path/to/file2.txt
    d
}' file1.txt
```

The `r file` command will read the text from `file` and insert it into the output stream. To also delete the `REPLACETHIS` text, we need the delete `d` command (heads-up: this will delete the complete line containing the text `REPLACETHIS`; if you need to use a mid-text marker, you could replace the `d` with `s///`, as noted by @ghoti).

In the first example, we had to break the `sed` program in two expressions, the reason being that `r command` has to end with a newline. The alternative is to write the program in several lines, as in the expanded example.

Also note that BSD `sed` handles `-i` option differently from GNU `sed`. The above will work in GNU, but if you need it for BSD, you should write: `-i ''` instead of `-i`.

Comment: You're right, I've just realized that myself. :) Fixed.

Comment: My answer didn't add much to yours once you fixed that. :)  Care to add a proviso regarding `REPLACETHIS` appearing on a line with other content, along perhaps with the mention of this type of `-i` use being a GNU sed-ism? (Questions are often platform-specific, but answers are always better if they're portable.)

Comment: Thanks, @ghoti. I think this does it. :)

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't strictly need to use `sed` for this at all.

```
file_to_change=/home/name/scripts/file1.txt
value=$(</home/name/scripts/file2.txt)
infile=$(<"$file_to_change")
tempfile=$(mktemp "$file_to_change.XXXXXX")
if printf '%s\n' "${infile//REPLACETHIS/$value}" >"$tempfile"; then
  mv -- "$tempfile" "$file_to_change"
else
  rm -f -- "$tempfile"
fi
```

This works even without `sed -i` (which is a nonstandard, nonportable, and incompatible between common implementations).